# Action isn't responding right now error

Tags: actions-on-google

I deployed an Actions on Google webhook (Actions SDK) and I am interacting with it using the simulator. However, I get the error message: "Action: action name isn’t responding right now. Try again soon." How can I troubleshoot this problem?

These are the steps I took to produce this error.

Deploy webhook. I verified that it is publicly accessible, uses HTTPS, and is capable of handling the [example request](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/conversation#request). It also sets the `Google-Assistant-API-Version` response header.

Point action.json to the publicly accessible webhook, then preview the action:

```
gactions --verbose preview --action_package=action.json -invocation_name="action name"
```

Start the simulator:

```
gactions --verbose simulate
```

Simulate an interaction:

```
Finished checking for updates -- no updates available
Reading credentials from: creds.data
User TTS (CTRL-C to stop): 
talk to action name
Sending POST request to: https://assistant.googleapis.com/v1/assistant:converse
Request body:
{
  "query": "talk to action name"
}

Response body:
{
  "response": "action name isn’t responding right now. Try again soon.\n",
  "audioResponse": "...",
  "debugInfo": {}
}
```

Although the message indicates that the action is not responding, I can see from my webhook logs that it is responding successfully with an HTTP status code of 200 and it is producing a JSON response that looks very similar to the [example responses](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/conversation#http-response).

What can be done to debug this issue?

On a side note, it looks like the actual request I am getting does not quite match the documentation. Here is an example of an actual request:

```
{"user":{"user_id":"..."},"conversation":{"conversation_id":"...","type":1},"inputs":[{"intent":"assistant.intent.action.MAIN","raw_inputs":[{"input_type":2,"query":"talk to action name"}],"arguments":[]}]}
```

Notice that `conversation.type` is an integer, not a String. In addition, no `conversation_token` is provided and thus, the `conversation_token` in the response I am generating is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more debug information using the [Web Simulator](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/web-simulator). Follow the same steps above, but after previewing the action using the `gactions` command, navigate to the [Web Simulator](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/web-simulator) and type in the same text you entered in the command-line simulator. This will fill in the `debugInfo` field in the JSON response.